# Why do not redirect maps work with static files?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure redirect_maps with nginx for a serie of PNG images that I moved to a folder. E.g. `/images/2022/stackoverflow.png` becomes `/images/anewfolder...`. I need to specify where the new path is so I was thinking about using redirect_maps.

In my configuration file, I have put:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri{
    /images/2022/stackoverflow.png /images/newfolder/stackoverflow.png;
}

server {
 [.. redacted for sensitive data ..]

     location / {

        if ($request_filename !~* .(gif|webp|jpe?g|png|json|ico|js|css|flv|swf|pdf|xml)$ ) {
            rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        }

        if ($redirect_uri){
            return 301 https://google.com$redirect_uri;
        }

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Option 2 for nginx:

```
location / {
                if ($redirect_uri){
                        return 301 https://google.com$redirect_uri;
                }

                rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URI will match the first if? I meant to write something like "if request_filename doest not end with .gif or .webp..."

Comment: @RichardSmith would anything change if I apply the second option?

Comment: I missed the `!` - you are right, the first block should not match. Look at the access log and ensure that the text after the GET exactly matches the value in your map. Are you sure that `location /` is processing the request?

Comment: For sure it is the exact same text because I'm copying-pasting, normal ASCII characters. The problem is that redirect_map does not handle so well the "." dot... If I write `/hello-world/ /new-page/;` it works without any issues.

Comment: Are there any other `location` blocks in your `server` block?

Comment: Oh, well, you asked the perfect question. I totally missed one location in my server block